# Bootstrap4 annotations on side of main text

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap4 page with text in a main central column. Toy example:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        MAIN TEXT HERE
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"/>
</div>
```

I want, at some points in the text, to add annotations on the right. One example is [OpenAI Blog](https://openai.com/blog/):
[image]

How can I achieve that in Bootstrap4? Do I have to break the text into different rows and insert the annotation in a lateral column? Or is there a better way of achieving this?

I don't really want to break the text as it would make it more difficult for people to add articles to my blog (using Jekyll with GitHub pages).

EDIT: Another way to achieve this would be to write all these annotations inside the right column. But how can I make them appear at the exact height that I want them to?

Comment: @FedericoTashin can you use javascript?

Comment: @FedericoTaschin, let's say we find a method to do it. How are you going to associate which annotation is related to which paragraph? HTML already has a tag called `aside` which can be used for such purposes.

Answer (score 1):

It's rather simple so I hope I'm not misunderstanding your question, but if you want an annotation to the right of a text paragraph with bootstrap, you could do it like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 annotation">Annotation text here</div>
</div>
```

And then in your css style the annotation:

```
.annotation {
    fontsize: 0.8em;
}
```

This would have the main text 9 cols wide to the left, and the annotations 3 cols wide to the right. With the css styling you can also add padding, margin, etc.

Comment: I thought about that, but I wanted to know if there is a way to do so without breaking the text. I mean, without having to put <div> and <row> tags in the middle of the text to achieve that.

Comment: Hmm, CSS grid sounds like the way to go if you want super flexible columns. But Bootstrap has a certain way of doing its own grid so you might be strapped by your boots there :) Also, you don't have to make a new row for every paragraph. That's why the p tag exists!

Comment: Thanks! But if I want to have a paragraph with an annotation on the side, then I do need to have in inside a <div class="row"> with a col-sm-9 for the text and col-sm-3 for the annotation, right?

Comment: If you want it on the exact same height and you want to use the bootstrap model, yes. You could work with margins as well, but that will get messy quick.

Comment: Is there a way to just have the text on the central column, and then all the annotations on a side column, "anchored" in height to specific parts of the text?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to anchor an element to a specific part of the text without using JS or another element in the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve without the need of Bootstrap. The trick is to write your paragraph in a `p` and inside of it you also write your annotation text in a `span` with a know class (let say `.annotation`). Then by using some `position: absolute` and `margin` you get your result with a valid HTML syntax:

```css
:root {
  --annotation-width: 30vw;
}

.texts {
  padding-right: var(--annotation-width);
}

.texts p {
  position: relative;
}

span.annotation {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: calc(-1 * var(--annotation-width)); /* used to generate `-30vw` */
  max-width: var(--annotation-width);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="texts">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
      sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
      rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      
      <span class="annotation">
        I'm an annotation. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
      </span>
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
      sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
      rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

      <span class="annotation">
        I'm another annotation
      </span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This would be very hard to maintain.

Comment: And why? the annotation is literally next his paragraph :/

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by working with Grid View with orders. Starting a Row and then seperating the Main Content and Annotation in two columns

(like col-sm-8 for main content and col-sm-4 for annotations)

For annotations, you have to keep the text center and alignments for that you have to use "d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center".

This will allows you to have Design as OpenAi

In order to bring the annotation to go top (only in small screen)

Use the "order", order-0 as first and order-1 as second, then bring order back to normal we have to use order-sm-0 as first and order-sm-1 as second.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-8 order-1 order-sm-0">
          *Main Text Here*
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur....<p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4 d-flex justify-content-left align-items-center order-0 order-sm-1">
     <small class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud...</small>
   </div>
</div>
```

If you want to bring the annotations only after some point then you could use some code like d-none d-sm-block...The Below Code will help you.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-8">
          *Main Text Here*
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur....<p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4 d-none d-sm-flex justify-content-left align-items-center">
     <small class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore...</small>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.newspaper {
  column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="newspaper">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.
</div>
```

You can use column-count.